# Changing workspace clobber option directly from Perforce command line

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

How to change perforce specs from command line?
What I want to do is, I have a workspace whose clobber option is set to `noclobber` (default value). Now I want to change it to `clobber`.

I know I can do it directly from `p4v`, but I don't want that. I also know that if I run `p4 client`, it will open P4CONFIG file in text editor, where I can change `noclobber` to `clobber` and save the file and it's done, but I also don't want that.

Please tell me the specific command which directly changes `noclobber` to `clobber` without using `p4v` or without editing P4CONFIG.

Comment: When you call 'p4 client' you will edit the options of the one particular client that you're working with. It doesn't affect any other clients. Why is that not sufficient in your case?
I don't know of any other way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy to script this with Perl, Python, Ruby, or even Powershell.  Here's a one-liner in Powershell:

`p4 client -o | %{$_ -replace "noclobber", "clobber"} | p4 client -i`

Comment: Great and thanks, this works well, i have created a python script for this.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you explain what is the syntax of `%{$_ -replace "noclobber", "clobber"}`? Is it a syntax of bash?

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to avoid repeatedly opening a text editor, you can accomplish your goal with a little bit of `sed`, like this:

```
p4 client -o | \
sed 's/ noclobber/ clobber/' | \
p4 client -i
```

Comment: I am not able to run this command in Win 7 command line promt. Is this a windows command, or should i make a bat file of this and run that?

Comment: @Niyojan, this is shell (usually `bash`) command. You can run it from any `bash`, `zsh` on windows. You can use `bash` from https://git-scm.com/download/win for example. Or you can even use more powerful https://www.cygwin.com/ (I would recommend to use 64bits version to avoid problems with 32bits version on 64bits windows).

Comment: You can also just download a copy of `sed` for Windows that will work with any shell, including `cmd`.  Googling "sed for windows" gets me this as the first hit, seems legit: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

Comment: Note, on windows replace single quote with double quotes in the sed command

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution:

```
P4EDITOR='sed -i s/noclobber/clobber/' p4 client
```

Comment: Could you please add a little bit more details about `P4EDITOR` env var? How exactly does it work?

Comment: `P4EDITOR` defines the editor program that's used to edit forms for all p4 commands.  If you use this method, make sure to unset it afterwards, or you'll be largely unable to use `p4`.  IMO it's better to just do `p4 client -o | sed s/noclobber/clobber/ | p4 client -i`.