# How can I set line ending setting for perforce workspace using p4 from command line?

Tags: ubuntu, perforce, line-endings

I cannot find documentation of how exactly to set the line ending settings for a workspace using p4 from the command line.  I know how to do this from p4v but I need to do it programmatically in a script and so using p4v isn't an option.

I know I can query the current state using the command

```
p4 client -o
```

I have found documentation about a setting `LineEnd` and the different values it can be set to of local, unix, mac, win, and share but I can't figure out or find documentation telling me how to actually issue the command to pass a new value.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See this answer to this more-or-less duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16302759/193453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is you do "p4 client -o" to get the current client spec, modify it, and then pass the modified version to "p4 client -i".

```
p4 client -o | sed -e "s/LineEnd:.*/LineEnd: unix/" | p4 client -i
```

Substitute your own value of LineEnd and/or your own sed replacement.